# How can I send filters parameters selected from Ant design Reacjs to nodejs backend?

Tags: reactjs, rest, integration, antd

**How can I send filters parameters selected from Ant design Reacjs to nodejs backend?**
I want to apply filtration. So for this purpose I make backend API which works correctly when I send data from **Postman**. Now I want that Filters data parameter should be send from fron-end(reactjs). How Can I send it from frontend using Ant design **Tree** component?
Here is my code:

```js
 // popup
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState(false);
  // dropdown tree states
  const [expandedKeys, setExpandedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [checkedKeys, setCheckedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [selectedKeys, setSelectedKeys] = useState([]);
  const [autoExpandParent, setAutoExpandParent] = useState(true);
  const [information, setInformation] = useState([])

  //   handle tree's categories functions
  const onExpand = (expandedKeys, info) => {
    console.log("onExpand info", info)
    console.log("onExpand", expandedKeys); // if not set autoExpandParent to false, if children expanded, parent can not collapse.
    // or, you can remove all expanded children keys.

    setExpandedKeys(expandedKeys);
    setAutoExpandParent(false);
  };

  const onCheck = (checkedKeys, info) => {
    // console.log("onCheck", checkedKeys)
    console.log("onCheck info", info.node)
    setCheckedKeys(checkedKeys);
    setInformation((prevSelected)=>[...prevSelected, info.node])
  };

  const onSelect = (selectedKeys, info) => {
    console.log("onSelect selectedKeys",selectedKeys)
    console.log("onSelect info", info);
    setSelectedKeys(selectedKeys);
  };
  // popup functions
  const showModal = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(true);
  };

  const handleOk = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setIsModalVisible(false);
  };

  const handleApplyFilter = ()=>{
    console.log("Apply button ", information);
  }
  
  
 const treeData = [
    {
      title: "Shelf Life",
      key: "0",
      checkable: false,
      children: [
        {
          title: "10",
          key: "0-1",
          checkable: true,
        },
        {
          title: "20",
          key: "0-2",
          checkable: true,
        }
      ],
    }
  ];
  
  
  return(
  <div>
  <div>
              <Button
                type="default"
                size="large"
                onClick={showModal}
                className="filteration"
              >
                <FilterOutlined /> Filters
              </Button>
              
              
              <Modal
              title="Filters"
              visible={isModalVisible}
              onOk={handleOk}
              onCancel={handleCancel}
              footer={[
                <Button key="1" onClick={()=>setCheckedKeys([])}>Reset</Button>,
                <Button key="2" type="primary" onClick={handleApplyFilter}>
                  Apply
                </Button>,
              ]}
            >
              <Tree
                checkable
                onExpand={onExpand}
                expandedKeys={expandedKeys}
                autoExpandParent={autoExpandParent}
                onCheck={onCheck}
                checkedKeys={checkedKeys}
                onSelect={onSelect}
                selectedKeys={selectedKeys}
                treeData={treeData}
              />
            </Modal>
            </div>
  </div>
  )
```

**Here is my post request which I send from Postman**
[image]

Now I want that when I click Apply button a post request is made to backend. Post request data will be similar to the data that I send from Postman.
Kindly Help me out! Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have two children in Shelf life. My question is do you want to send a single value for shelf life? According to above, you can select multiple values for shelf life.

Comment: Nouman Bhai! I have updated the postman picture. Kindly check it again. And Yes I can send single value of shelf life as well as multiple values. If user select multiple values then surely multiple values will be post in request

Comment: Kindly check the code again I have updated a little bit. Now on select we can get more info. about the selected item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In treeData, add a parent and value key in each children node/object:

```
const treeData = [
        {
            title: 'Shelf Life',
            key: '0',
            parent: 'shelfLife',
            checkable: false,
            children: [
                {
                    title: '10',
                    key: '0-1',
                    value: 10,
                    parent: 'shelfLife',
                    checkable: true
                },
                {
                    title: '20',
                    key: '0-2',
                    value: 20,
                    parent: 'shelfLife',
                    checkable: true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Trade Name',
            key: '1',
            checkable: false,
            children: [
                {
                    title: 'Head & Shoulder',
                    value: 'Head & Shoulder',
                    parent: 'tradeName',
                    key: '1-1'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

Now create a new state:

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState<any>({});
```

When you check any checkbox, it will call onCheck function.

```
    const onCheck = (checkedKeys, info) => {
        setCheckedKeys(checkedKeys);

        let parent = info.node.parent;

        setFilter((prev) => {
            let keys = { ...prev };
            keys[parent] = info.checkedNodes.filter((item) => item.parent === parent).map((item) => item.value);
            return keys;
        });
    };
```

Here each node have its parent key. In info, we have `checkedNodes` which have all the nodes that are marked checked. I just mapped over them and get the value from each node and assign the array to parent of that node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nouman for your response! It works for only parent and child but  does not work if I add another parent and child? How it can be handled? I want if it add another attribute then previous data should not add into this one

Comment: Add all the parent and child attributes, i will update my answer. 
So you want one filter to be send at a time?

Comment: No No. User can send multiple parent's child. Like here I have Only shelfLife. There might be another array of object of tradeName. so user can select trade name as well as shelfLife

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now you can multiple parents with their children values. You can check the attach screenshot

Comment: I m beginner in react js so that's why i m asking too many question.  I want to ask last question. How can I post this dafa in the form as shown in Postman image. I want to post it Like similary way. Kindly last time update the code to send api post request using axios in similar way as shown in Postman image

Comment: `let data = { filteration: filter };`

`axios.post('http://localhost:4002/v1/getMarketPlace', data);`
You can send data like this

Comment: @AbdulSammad you can as many questions as you want. But just follow this pattern. `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts`. 
I just want to help others.